# Spring.net Nhibernate dao is null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, spring.net

I followed the spring.net documentation and the northwind example.

BereikDao

```
[Repository]
public class BereikDao : HibernateDao, IBereikDao
{
    [Transaction(ReadOnly = true)]
    public model.Bereik getById(int id)
    {
        return CurrentSession.Get<Bereik>(id);
    }

    [Transaction(ReadOnly = true)]
    public IList<Bereik> getAll()
    {
        return getAll<Bereik>();
    }
}
```

HibernateDao

```
public abstract class HibernateDao
{
    private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /// <summary>
    /// Session factory for sub-classes.
    /// </summary>
    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        protected get { return sessionFactory; }
        set { sessionFactory = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get's the current active session. Will retrieve session as managed by the 
    /// Open Session In View module if enabled.
    /// </summary>
    protected ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); }
    }

    protected IList<T> getAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        ICriteria criteria = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria<T>();
        return criteria.List<T>();
    }
}
```

spring-dao.xml

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.net/tx">
    <db:provider id="DbProvider"
                       provider="IfxOdbc" connectionString="Dsn=${db.dsn};Host=${db.host};Server=${db.server};Service=${db.service};Database=${db.database};UID=${db.user};Password=${db.password};"/>
  <object id="appConfigPropertyHolder"
         type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
     <property name="configSections" value="databaseSettings"/>
      </object>
      <object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" type="Demo.dao.CustomLocalSessionFactoryObject">
        <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
        <property name="MappingAssemblies">
          <list>
            <value>Demo</value>
          </list>
        </property>
        <property name="HibernateProperties">
          <dictionary>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
            <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.InformixDialect1000"/>
            <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.IfxDriver"/>
            <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />
          </dictionary>
        </property>


    <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />


    </object>

  <object id="transactionManager"
        type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate33">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
  </object>

  <object type="Spring.Dao.Attributes.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, Spring.Data"/>

  <object id="bereikDao" type="Demo.dao.BereikDao">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
  </object>

  <object id="bereikService" type="Demo.service.impl.BereikService">
    <property name="bereikDao" ref="bereikDao"/>
  </object>

  <tx:attribute-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-type="true"/>


</objects>
```

BereikService

```
public class BereikService : IBereikService
{
    private IBereikDao _bereikDao;

    public IBereikDao bereikDao
    {
        get { return _bereikDao; }
        set { _bereikDao = value; }
    }

    [Transaction]
    public IList<model.Bereik> getAll()
    {

        return _bereikDao.getAll();
    }
}
```

And in my application:

```
bereikService = (BereikService)ctx.GetObject("bereikService");
IList<Bereik> bereiken = bereikService.getAll();
```

When debugging bereikDao in bereikService is null.

Suddenly the following error:

```
'Errors' node cannot be resolved for the specified context [System.InvalidCastException: Kan een object van het type System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection niet converteren naar het type IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.
   bij IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.set_Connection(IDbConnection value)
   bij NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.Prepare(IDbCommand cmd) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:regel 112
   bij NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:regel 217
   bij NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:regel 1226
   bij NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:regel 421
   bij NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:regel 251
   bij NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:regel 1564].
```

translated: Cannot convert object of System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection to IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.
Nhibernate bug?

From the debug:

```
Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as ADO transaction [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection]
```

Comment: What happens if you do `var myDao = (IBereikDao)ctx.GetObject("bereikDao");`?

Comment: Additional information: Kan een object van het type DecoratorAopProxy_493459a5f40e441ba75921dbae1516e4 niet converteren naar het type Demo.dao.BereikDao.

Comment: Looks like your atttempting to convert an aop proxy (created for transaction support) to a concrete type. sure you're not doing `(BereikDao)ctx.GetObject("bereikDao");` (look at the cast)? what does `var obj = ctx.GetObject("bereikDao")` do? En het is beter om je stacktraces in het Engels te geven - er zijn veel minder mensen die Nederlands kunnen lezen :)

Comment: myDao = (IBereikDao)ctx.GetObject("bereikDao"); works but I'm still getting the odbcconection error

Comment: looks to me as if you configured a batcher which is incompatible with your dialect. Can you post the configuration plz?

Comment: Firo, the spring-dao.xml in the question is the only configuration I have besides some spring config for logging, parsers,..

Answer (score 0):

LET ME KNOW IF YOU STILL GET AN ERROR AFTER DOING THIS.

Start with adding the object reference to Dao.XML and bind it to the SessionFactory as follows:

```
<object id="BereikDao" type="Spring.Northwind.Dao.NHibernate.HibernateBereikDao,     Spring.Northwind.Dao.NHibernate">
<property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
</object>
```

You also have to add the object reference to Service.xml and bind it to BereikDao as follows:

```
<object id="BereikService" type="Spring.Northwind.Service.BereikService, Spring.Northwind.Service">
<property name="BereikDao" ref="BereikDao"/>
</object>
```

Comment: My apologies for the very late reply.
I can't test it because I'm still having this error:  Cannot convert object of System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection